# What is the right way use ARC when present viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

Every time I present my new viewcontroller (as property in presenter vc) as show below:

```
if(self.viewController) [self.viewController release];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

so I'm always guaranteed to get a new instance of object (if the object already exists).

But now I use ARC and don't have any ideas how to send my object release message (because is not work with ARC)

Can you help me with this issues?

PS: Every time when I present gameVC I need an new instance of the object.

Thanks all!

Comment: You (generally) don't need to send release messages to your objects with ARC. Apple's compiler will put release messages in your code on compilation whenever it's appropriate.

Comment: That should read "You *can't* send release messages to your objects with ARC."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

the above code will always presents a new vc and apple's compiler will take care of the release.

But if you think the above have some problem(which is a myth) then you can do also like this

```
self.viewController = nil;
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have some questions: my presenter vc is singleton and when I finished use my viewController (presented) I calling method in singleton vc (presenter) and want to dismiss presented vc in this method. so, for example vc A present B. using B some time. For example I finish use B vc and want recreate B again. In A vc i call the method [B dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and make alloc and present for B vc, but I don't see vc. (viewDidLoad is execute, but view not showing).

Comment: please put another question as well as the code.. try animation `NO`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler puts the release instruction for you. You should use only this code and it should work OK:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

is the right way.

However, this code is OK even when you're using Manual Reference Counting, assuming that `viewController` is a property of `self` with `retain` or `strong` flag. When you're changing the property value, previous property value gets released, so you don't need to release it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hold a pointer to your view controller.
I'm pretty sure your code should look like this:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: What if he wants a reference to it though? It's perfectly valid to keep a reference to it.

Comment: Yeah, but not when you want a new object every time this code is executed.

Comment: But his method *does* give a new object each time *and* keeps a reference to it. He might want to interact with the VC that's currently presented, for instance.